# admin generator fields not translated

Tags: symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I am creating a symfony 1.4 app in which i included sfGuardDoctrinePlugin.
In order to manage users, I use an admin generator :

```
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           sfGuardUser
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          utilisateur
    with_doctrine_route:   true

  config:
    fields:
    first_name:       { label: "Prénom" }
    last_name:        { label: "Nom" }
    username:         { label: "Login" }
    password:         { label: "Mot de passe" }
    password_again:   { label: "Confirmation" }
    email_address:    { label: "E-mail" }
    is_active:        { label: "Actif" }
    last_login:       { label: "Dernière cnx" }
    # groups_list:      { label: "Groupes" }
    permissions_list: { label: "Permissions" }

  list:
    title:   Liste des utilisateurs
    display: [=username, first_name, last_name, is_active, last_login]

  filter:
    class: false

  form:
    class: sfGuardUserAdminForm
    display:
      "Utilisateur": [first_name, last_name, email_address, username, password, password_again]
      "Permissions": [is_active, permissions_list]

  edit:
    title: Modifier l'utilisateur "%%username%%"

  new:
    title: Nouvel utilisateur
```

Everything is allright, but I can't get the last_login, email_address, and is_active fields translated, as configured in the fields section.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Jérémie

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can edit your translations for example in

```
app/backend/i18n/fr/messages.xml
```

In my case:

```
 <!-- sfGuardUser user form -->
      <trans-unit id="6">
        <source>User</source>
        <target>Користувач</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="7">
        <source>First name</source>
        <target>Ім'я</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="8">
        <source>Last name</source>
        <target>Прізвище</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="9">
        <source>Email address</source>
        <target>Email</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="10">
        <source>Password (again)</source>
        <target>Пароль (знову)</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="11">
        <source>Permissions and groups</source>
        <target>Права та групи</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="12">
        <source>Is active</source>
        <target>Активний</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="13">
        <source>Is super admin</source>
        <target>Супер адмін</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="14">
        <source>Groups</source>
        <target>Групи</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="15">
        <source>Permissions</source>
        <target>Права</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <!-- End sfGuardUser user form -->
```

Don't forget clear cache.